# Is there a git GUI that batches calls to git checkout?

Tags: windows, git

I've been using TortoiseGit for many years and it is very slow for certain operations. Specifically, it does not batch calls to `git checkout`.

For example, say I use the TortoiseGit "Revert" function on 20 files: This will result in 20 individual calls to `git checkout` (along with other processing?), which takes a very long time to do (about 20 seconds). If I was to do this from the command line, I would use one call that would look something like `git checkout -- file1 file2 file3 etc...` and this entire operation would complete in less than a second because only one call to `git checkout` was made.

Are there any git GUI clients out there that will give the option to batch checkout files like this: `git checkout -- file1 file2 file3 etc...` instead of making a separate call for each selected file?